# How to update a separate item in Yii2 listview using socket.io

Tags: node.js, listview, redis, socket.io, yii2

An issue is the following.

I have a View.php with just an unique id and text inside. This View.php is assigned to the Yii2 ListView 'itemView' option. After rendering it looks like this:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
```

How to update the text of the row with id=2 in real time. For such kind of updates I am using Yii2 + redis + nodejs + socket.io and I can update separate elements outside the ListView. But I cannot understand how to update an element if it is inside of some row (View.php) rendered by ListView. Thanks!

My code is the following:
From Yii I send data to redis channel 'notification':

```
return Yii::$app->redis->executeCommand('PUBLISH', [
            'channel' => 'notification',
            'message' => Json::encode(['name' => $name, 'id' => $id, 'message' => $message])
        ]);
```

My nodejs server is listening for redis and emit data further to socket of target user:

```
redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("New message: " + message + ". In channel: " + channel);
        var message1 = JSON.parse(message);
        connectedUsers[message1.id].emit(channel, message);
    });
```

The socket of target user is listening for channel (event) 'notification' and make changes of elements if necessary (in this example just prepend message to div with id notifications(inside index.php file)):

```
socket.on('notification', function (data) {

        var message = JSON.parse(data);

        $( "#notifications" ).prepend( "<p><strong>" + message.name + "</strong>: " + message.message + "</p>" );

    });
```

In my index.php I have also a listView

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ListView;
...
echo ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_item',
] ); ?>
```

The View file _item.php contains:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>  

<?=$model->id;?> 
<?=$model->name;?>
```

So how to indicate inside the client socket that I need to change 'name' of the row with received id (it is obtained with message from Yii).

Comment: show your code  ..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue as following:

ListView code (in this example I used ArrayDataProvider):

```
echo ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return $this->render('_item',['model' => $model]);}
] ); ?>
```

Array and dataProvider used in this example:

```
$arr = [
    ['ID' => 'A1', 'Description' => 'Item 1'],
    ['ID' => 'A2', 'Description' => 'Item 2'],
    ['ID' => 'A3', 'Description' => 'Item 3'],
    ['ID' => 'A4', 'Description' => 'Item 4'],
    ['ID' => 'A5', 'Description' => 'Item 5'],
];
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
'allModels' => $arr,
'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 5]
]);
```

Note: Each row in array represents an independent model

_item.php View code:

```
<div id= "<?php echo $model['ID'] ?>">
    <?php echo 'ID = '.$model['ID'] ?>
</div>
```

update client socket (notification.js):

```
document.getElementById("message.id").innerHTML = "<p><strong>" + message.name + "</strong>: " + message.message + "</p>";
```

So an idea is to assign an unique 'model id' to each row (to 'id' of div element) in rendered ListView.
Then based on received id (from Yii2 via redis and nodejs server) we can play with the content of the row.